# Admin-sdk custom CMS element not displaying the Layout assignment

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-app

I followed this doc https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/content/cms/add-cms-element-via-admin-sdk.html, to create a custom CMS element. it works well on CMS page

Then I assign that CMS page to a landing page, the CMS element config is not rendered.

I see some console errors like the below screenshot.

[image]

do we have any document about implementing of Admin-sdk CMS element on Layout assignment?